# Best SSE method for getting file upload progress?

Tags: ajax, html, file-upload, progress, server-sent-events

I am coding a backwards compatible file upload progress for AJAX. In HTML5 there is the xhr.upload.progress event; this would be an alternative for non-XHR2 browsers. I am using the APC extension to monitor the progress.

Now, my question is: which is the best method for firing a custom-built xhr.upload.progress event? I plan to use HTML5 SSE's, but if they are not supported, I'm not sure what I should fall back to.

1. Polling: continuous AJAX requests for the progress every couple seconds
2. Long-polling: apparently better than polling? though, I hear they cause the server to freeze up, because the requests aren't really handled asynchronously on the server. So, I'm assuming I would have to implement something like NodeJS to avoid that. If the freezing-up problem has just been overstated/overdramatized, I'd probably go with long-polling.
3. Un-ending iframe: the iframe seems like a good idea, but I'm sure there are problems with it. Does it freeze up the server like long-polling too?

Edit:
I guess, here are my primary concerns. What is the scalability of these AJAX methods? Do EventSource SSE's freeze-up the server's memory as well? If so, should I consider using something like NodeJS or ScaleStack? And, does server overhead really matter with an upload bar?

Answer (score 1):

All these solutions require you to do some server-side work too while the best solution would be client-side only. For now, I'm using a Flash component Uploadify to do that job.

http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: Sure but creating more requests and responses is going to slow down the initial upload.

Comment: True, but I'm looking for an answer to my question, not an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, you may use SSE polyfill as a fallback: https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource — you won't have to write extra code for non-SSE browsers.

A completely different approach could be to track upload progress in JS, client-side. Relatively new [XHR2 and FormData](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) APIs make that possible.